# How can can I override the Android system service LocationManager (GPS) for select applications?

Tags: android, service, gps, locationmanager

I am looking to override [android.location.LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).
The goal will be to hand pick what data is returned to whichever application calls it. In other words, I am aiming to "fool" already existing applications to think that my code is the LocationManager when they call:

```
Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)
```

*E.G.: Google Maps will get the true GPS data & Facebook will get obfuscated or falsified GPS data.*

Much searching has led me to the closest solution here: http://pedroassuncao.com/2009/11/android-location-provider-mock/ where there is code that feeds GPS data directly into the LocationManager.  However, I see no way of moding it to do what I am aiming for.

Optimally, I would like run it as a service and not a modification to the OS itself.

Comment: Seems to me that it would be a security issue if things like that were possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am looking to override android.location.LocationManager.

Fortunately, this is not possible, except perhaps via custom firmware, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: All the main OS classes are signed by Google.  Therefore, one must build a custom version of the OS and install on a rooted device to accomplish this.